# How to add a device to provisioning profile automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I want to allow my users to install my iOS app with ad-hoc distribution. I want to get their UDIDs and add them to the provisioning profile automatically. I know how to do it manually in the developer portal but what I need is an api to do this process automatically not manually.

- Does apple provide any api or other means to add devices to provisioning profile automatically?

(Note that I do not have any device available. I just have their UDIDs)

Comment: you can set automatically signing .
using this xcode will automatically create and update profiles, appids and certificates..
and you can register new device by one click

Answer (score 1):

Xcode will automatically add your devices into your provisioning profile. You will see a warning about that on xcode. You can click "Register" button on it.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below steps

1. Login to your iphone provisioning portal through developer.apple.com
2. Add the UDID in devices
3. Go back to XCode, open up the Organizer and select "Provisioning Profiles", ensure that "Automatic Device Provisioning" is checked on the top right pane, then click on the "Refresh" button, and magically all your devices set in the provisioning portal will be automatically added.